# Twython 401 error when trying to update with media

Tags: python, twitter, twython

I am trying to get my raspberry pi to watch twitter for tweets at a certain user using a certain hashtag. When it sees a tweet that meets the criteria, it should take a picture and then tweet the picture back at the user. It works up until the point where it should upload the picture, and then I get a "Twitter API returned a 401 (Unauthorized)". I don't know why it is returning a 401 because the credentials work earlier for the streaming portion of the script. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
from twython import Twython
from twython import TwythonStreamer
import sys
import os

APP_KEY = 'X'
APP_SECRET = 'X'
OAUTH_TOKEN = 'X'
OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET = 'X'

def takePicture(id_str, screen_name):
    os.system('raspistill -o ' + str(id_str) + '_@' + str(screen_name) + '.png -t 3000 -w 1080 -h 720 -n -vf')

def photo(id_str, screen_name):
    open('/home/pi/' + str(id_str) + '_@' + str(screen_name) + '.png', 'rb')

def uppic(screen_name):
    twitter.update_status_with_media(status='@' + str(screen_name) + ' is super awesome!', media=photo)

class MyStreamer(TwythonStreamer):
    def on_success(self, data):
        print data['user']['screen_name'].encode('utf-8')
        print data['id_str'].encode('utf-8')
        print data['text'].encode('utf-8')
        takePicture(data['id_str'], data['user']['screen_name'])
        photo(data['id_str'], data['user']['screen_name'])
        uppic(data['user']['screen_name'])

    def on_error(elf, status_code, data):
        print status_code

stream = MyStreamer(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)
twitter = Twython(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)

stream.statuses.filter(track='#hashtag @user')
```

Answer (score 0):

I created new oauth secrets and that resolved the problem. However, now it returns:

"TwythonError: Twitter API returned a 403 (Forbidden), Missing or invalid url parameter."